# Standard Haskell function to expand environment variables

Tags: haskell, path, environment-variables

I'm looking for something similar to Python's `os.path.expandvars` in Haskell, i.e., a `FilePath -> IO FilePath` function that is

- Cross-platform (supports both Windows `%VAR%` and Unix `$VAR` styles)
- Standard (I don't want to write my own function for that).

Example:

```
> expandVars "$HOME/foo/bar"
"/home/someuser/foo/bar"
```

I've searched on Hoogle, Hayoo and Google but found nothing, which is surprising given the number of cross-platform Haskell tools. The closest I found is [this Unix-only implementation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/chatty-0.7.0.1/docs/src/Text-Chatty-Expansion-Vars.html). Perhaps there is some project which implements this as a subroutine?

Comment: I don't think this questions should be closed. In case you're still interested in Haskell solution, I discovered this library which can help you to deal with environment variables: https://github.com/stackbuilders/dotenv-hs